# Intent using thread is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

I know I already asked this, but I didn't get a sufficient answer. Im trying to start an activity, but the emulator stays on the first activity. Ive tried all ways to do it but it never works. The youtube videos show that it should work but it never does. Is there something missing or is there anything wrong with the following code?

```
//First Activity:


package com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Opening extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent open = new Intent("com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame.MENU");
                startActivity(open);
            }

        }
    };
    timer.start();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.opening, menu);
    return true;
}

}

//Second Activity:

package com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


//Created by suprav on 7/11/13.

public class Menu extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
}
}

//Android Manifest:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame.Opening"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame.Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
        android:parentActivityName="Opening" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame.MENU"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="Opening" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in logcat

Comment: Do you have it added to Manifest?

Comment: What does your sleep method do? I assume it sleeps, but its the only piece we don't have here... Also using the name of the activity to start is probably unnecessary.  Just use the class as suggested in an answer below.

Comment: Since everything seems to be in order, the only possible issue i can think of is the <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="Opening" /> Tag, that might be causing a conflict as data propertie does if is not properly used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the issue, seems like metadata property is not being properly used, hences activity its not being started, this is the proper way to use the property:

```
  <activity android:name=".TestActivity" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
              android:value=".TestParentActivity">
        </meta-data>
  </activity>
```

So, seems like you are missing a dot in "android:value="Opening"

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Intent open = new Intent(Opening.this, Menu.class);
startActivity(open);
```